# Haskell: Possible fix: add (Eq a) to the context of

Tags: haskell, tree, compiler-errors, typeclass

I'm kind of new to Haskell and I'm having a hard time understanding what is wrong with my code here.

**Here is what I'm supposed to do:**
*Consider the following definition of a binary tree*

```
data BinaryTree a = Empty | Node a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)
```

*Consider the function reflect that forms the mirror image of a binary tree by exchanging left and right all the way down*

```
reflect :: BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a  
reflect Empty = Empty  
reflect (Node x l r) = Node x (reflect r) (reflect l)
```

*Write a function areMirrorImages that determines whether two binary trees t and u satisfy 
t = reflect u. The function should not build new trees, so it should not call reflect or Node; although it may use Node in patterns.*

**Here is what I've written:**

```
areMirrorImages :: BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool  
areMirrorImages Empty Empty = True  
areMirrorImages (Node _ _ _) Empty = False  
areMirrorImages Empty (Node _ _ _) = False  
areMirrorImages (Node x l r) (Node y ll rr)  
    | x==y = ((areMirrorImages l rr) && (areMirrorImages r ll))  
    | otherwise = False
```

When I try running it I get the following error on line 49:
Could not deduce (Eq a) from the context () arising from a use of '=='
Possible fix: add (Eq a) to the context of the type signature for 'areMirrorImages'
In the expression: x==y

I am confused as to why I'm getting this error and I tried finding solutions online but I have found nothing so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At the moment, your binary trees can hold any type whatsoever - even types that can't be compared using `==`. So if you called `areMirrorImages` on a tree containing such a type ... what should happen?

What you need to do is place a *constraint* on the `areMirrorImages` function, so that it can only accept binary trees that it can compare the contents of.

Something like the following:

```
areMirrorImages :: Eq a => BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool
```

Answer (score 6):

Just as a little side note: It's often a good idea to put all "matching" cases of a function at the top, as this often simplifies the "non-matching" ones:

```
areMirrorImages :: Eq a => BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool
areMirrorImages Empty Empty = True  
areMirrorImages (Node x l r) (Node y ll rr) = 
    and [x==y, areMirrorImages l rr, areMirrorImages r ll]  
areMirrorImages _ _ = False
```