# Haskell- recursively check elements of associative list

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, tuples

Say I have the following associative list:

```
names = [(6548712, "Charlie Brown"), (27378912, "Linux Van Pelt"), (5831457, "Peppermint Patty")]
```

I want to check if a given tuple, such as...

```
 (6548712, "Charlie Brown")
```

...exists within the associative list.

Here is my function:

```
check :: (String,a) -> [(String,a)] -> Bool
check val (x:xs)
    | x == val = True
    | otherwise = check val xs
```

The function does not work. I think the error lies in my first guard, since I do believe my recursive call is correct. I want to be able to do this using recursion, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your data has Number and String but your function reads String and Number. So that has to be changed to this

   ```
   check :: (Int, String) -> [(Int, String)] -> Bool
   ```
2. Your recursion should have a base condition, like this

   ```
   check val [] = False
   ```

   It means that if the list is empty (all elements are checked), return `False`.

So your function should look like this

```
check :: (Int, String) -> [(Int, String)] -> Bool

check val [] = False
check val (x:xs)
    | x == val = True
    | otherwise = check val xs
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/NVw0j0)

---

As it is, you can make your function Polymorphic by doing

```
check :: Eq a => (a, String) -> [(a, String)] -> Bool
```

To know more about `Eq a`, please check [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5012238/1903116)

---

Just for the sake of completion, you can always use [`elem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) function, like this

```
Prelude> elem (6548712, "Charlie Brown") [(6548712, "Charlie Brown"), (27378912, "Linux Van Pelt"), (5831457, "Peppermint Patty")]
True
```

Comment: Also, the function can be more polymorphic.

Comment: It can be more concise: `check :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` :)

Comment: @Sibi Right, but this looks more clear and easy to understand right? :)

Comment: I agree with that. :)